# How do Colorfy app developers keep the size of the app small even though it contains many images?

Tags: android, ios, windows

How do Colorfy app developers keep the size of the app small even though it contains many images inside the app for people to color? I assume the images they have in the app should be in PNG format? so, with all those images inside the app for people to color, the size of the app should be several hundred megabytes rathe than 50Mb?

Comment: a PNG image of 1080x1920 resolution can be optimised to as low as 10KB. especially if its a black and white line drawing, you can get some serious size reduction. search for TinyPNG.

Comment: or see [this](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html) if thats your kind of thing.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a PNG image of 1080x1920 resolution can be optimised to as low as 10KB. especially if its a black and white line drawing, you can get some serious size reduction. see [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to compress your images with www.tinypng.com to decrease size of your images. This site will compress images with same clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Welcome lollipop, if you found any doubt in compress than inform me i will help you.